# Mysql : Loada data in file from dataset having column names inside

Tags: mysql

I have column names: 'date', 'firsts', 'seconds', 'thirds' and 'last' which are inside the dataset too, such as:

```
["date":"2018-03-12","firsts":4,"seconds":6,"thirds":7,"last":2,],["date":"2018-03-13","firsts":2,"seconds":1,"thirds":6,"last":2,],["date":"2018 as-03-14",...
```

This is a continuous `data set where date (subsets)` are separated by '[ ]'.
Is there some way to load this direct into `DB` here I ill get only data in corresponding columns?

```
2018-03-12 |4 | 6 | 7 | 2
2018-03-13 | 2 |1 | 6 | 2
...
```

Comment: This looks like JSON data.  I would probably either write a short script in an app language like Java which parses the JSON into a format which `LOAD DATA` can use, or maybe try to go to the source of your data and request pure CSV.

Comment: Thank you Tim. Yes, I considered the script option and will probably do that. I hoped there was some way to parse column names/values directly from the file.

Comment: Also thank you for pointing to JSON data. That could be used too.

Comment: The thing is, there is a way for `LOAD DATA` to apply a function to a column, but AFAIK it is one-to-one only, i.e. you may map one column to the same slot.  But what you would need here is to read in one column and generate multiple columns.  I don't think `LOAD DATA` can handle this.